How to customize MUI Date Picker buttons
How can I change teh background color of a selected shortcut item in the staticDateRangePicker?
For example when I click on button today and it is selected I want the background color to be 'grey' to let the user know it is being filtered.
Date picker
import { Box, Button } from '@mui/material';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import { DateCalendar } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DateCalendar';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { pickersLayoutClasses } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/PickersLayout';
import { PickersShortcutsItem } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/PickersShortcuts';
import { DateRange } from '@mui/x-date-pickers-pro';
import { StaticDateRangePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers-pro/StaticDateRangePicker';
import dayjs, { Dayjs } from 'dayjs';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import { getEndOfDay } from '@/helpers/getEndOfDay';
import { getStartOfDay } from '@/helpers/getStartOfDay';
import useStore from '@/hooks/useStore';

const getShortcutsItems = (
  setDashboardDefaultStartDate: (date: Dayjs | null) => void,
  setDashboardDefaultEndDate: (date: Dayjs | null) => void
): PickersShortcutsItem<DateRange<Dayjs>>[] => [
  {
    label: 'Today',
    getValue: () => {
      const start = getStartOfDay(dayjs());
      const end = getEndOfDay(dayjs());
      return [start, end];
    },
  },
  {
    label: '2 Weeks',
    getValue: () => {
      const start = getStartOfDay(dayjs().subtract(2, 'week').add(1, 'day'));
      const end = getEndOfDay(dayjs());
      return [start, end];
    },
  },
  {
    label: '1 Month',
    getValue: () => {
      const start = getStartOfDay(dayjs().subtract(1, 'month').add(1, 'day'));
      const end = getEndOfDay(dayjs());
      return [start, end];
    },
  },
  {
    label: '2 Months',
    getValue: () => {
      const start = getStartOfDay(dayjs().subtract(2, 'month').add(2, 'day'));
      const end = getEndOfDay(dayjs());
      return [start, end];
    },
  },
  {
    label: 'All',
    getValue: () => {
      setDashboardDefaultStartDate(null);
      setDashboardDefaultEndDate(null);
      return [null, null];
    },
  },
];

interface DateRangePickerProps {
  handlePickerClose: () => void;
}

const DateRangePicker = ({ handlePickerClose }: DateRangePickerProps) => {
  const {
    uiStore: {
      filterStartDate,
      filterEndDate,
      dashboardDefaultStartDate,
      dashboardDefaultEndDate,
      setFilterStartDate,
      setFilterEndDate,
      setDashboardDefaultStartDate,
      setDashboardDefaultEndDate,
    },
  } = useStore();

  useEffect(() => {
    setComponentFilterStartDate(filterStartDate ?? dashboardDefaultStartDate);
    setComponentFilterEndDate(filterEndDate ?? dashboardDefaultEndDate);
  }, [
    filterStartDate,
    filterEndDate,
    dashboardDefaultStartDate,
    dashboardDefaultEndDate,
  ]);

  const [componentFilterStartDate, setComponentFilterStartDate] =
    useState<null | Dayjs>(null);
  const [componentFilterEndDate, setComponentFilterEndDate] =
    useState<null | Dayjs>(null);

  const [showMonthCalendar, setShowMonthCalendar] = useState(false);

  const shortcutsItems = getShortcutsItems(
    setDashboardDefaultStartDate,
    setDashboardDefaultEndDate
  );

  const handleDataChange = (date: DateRange<Dayjs>) => {
    const isOnlyOneDaySelected = dayjs(date[0]).isSame(date[1], 'day');

    setShowMonthCalendar(false);
    setFilterStartDate(date[0]);

    if (isOnlyOneDaySelected) {
      setFilterEndDate(getEndOfDay(date[0] as Dayjs));
    } else {
      setFilterEndDate(date[1]);
    }
  };

  const handleMonthChange = (date: Dayjs) => {
    setShowMonthCalendar(false);
    setFilterStartDate(date.startOf('month'));
    setFilterEndDate(date.endOf('month'));
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} adapterLocale="de">
        <Box
          sx={{
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'column',
          }}
        >
          <Box
            sx={{
              position: 'absolute',
              color: 'white',
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              top: 20,
              left: 20,
              width: 170,
              height: 20,
              cursor: 'pointer',
              zIndex: 100,
            }}
            onClick={() => {
              setShowMonthCalendar(!showMonthCalendar);
            }}
          ></Box>
          {showMonthCalendar ? (
            <Box
              sx={{
                position: 'absolute',
                zIndex: 100,
                height: 350,
                backgroundColor: 'black',
              }}
            >
              <DateCalendar
                onMonthChange={handleMonthChange}
                defaultValue={filterStartDate ?? dayjs()}
                views={['year', 'month']}
                minDate={dayjs('2010-01-01')}
                maxDate={dayjs()}
                openTo="month"
              />
            </Box>
          ) : null}
          <StaticDateRangePicker
            showDaysOutsideCurrentMonth={true}
            dayOfWeekFormatter={(_day, weekday) => `${weekday.format('ddd')}`}
            value={[componentFilterStartDate, componentFilterEndDate]}
            onChange={handleDataChange}
            slotProps={{
              layout: {
                sx: {
                  [`.${pickersLayoutClasses.shortcuts}`]: {
                    gridColumn: 3,
                    backgroundColor: '#ffffff08',
                    paddingTop: '60px',
                    width: 145,
                  },
                  [`.MuiButtonBase-root`]: {
                    borderRadius: '20px',
                    textTransform: 'none',
                  },
                  [`.MuiChip-root`]: {
                    color: '#FAFAFA',
                    fontSize: 16,
                    border: '1px solid #FAFAFA',
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                    '&:hover': {
                      backgroundColor: 'grey',
                    },
                  },
                  [`.MuiListItem-root`]: {
                    pb: '15px',
                  },
                },
              },
              toolbar: {
                hidden: true,
              },
              shortcuts: {
                items: shortcutsItems,
              },
              actionBar: {
                actions: [],
              },
            }}
          />
          <Box sx={{ backgroundColor: '#181623' }}>
            <Button
              sx={{
                width: '1em',
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                display: 'flex',
                ml: 'auto',
                mr: 1.8,
                mb: 2,
                '&:hover': {
                  backgroundColor: 'red',
                },
              }}
              onClick={() => {
                handlePickerClose();
              }}
            >
              Apply
            </Button>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </LocalizationProvider>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default observer(DateRangePicker);


I have tried updating my shortcutsItems but that did not work and I get error on .getValue()
const shortcutsItems = getShortcutsItems(
  setDashboardDefaultStartDate,
  setDashboardDefaultEndDate
).map((item) => ({
  ...item,
  onClick: () => {
    const dateRange = item.getValue();
    if (Array.isArray(dateRange)) {
      handleDataChange(dateRange);
    }
    setSelectedLabel(item.label);
  },
  sx: {
    backgroundColor: selectedLabel === item.label ? 'grey' : 'transparent',
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: selectedLabel === item.label ? 'darkgrey' : 'grey',
    },
  },
}));

